# Asp.net Azure WebApp publish Website but no Picture

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I published my azure website (asp.net with c# controller) as a WebApp but when I call the website there are no picture.

If I deploy the website on LocalHost I can see the picture.

```
        <img class="img-responsive" style="height:90%;width:90%" src="../Content/images/test.png" />
```

I also tried to change the path to:

```
src="~/Content/images/test.png" /

src="/Content/images/test.png" /
```

But after uploading the webapp I cannot see any picture.

In other question I read that I have to use Azure Blob Storage. But I just have a few (ca. 5 picture) on my website. Maybe there is a simpler way?

Or is it possible to upload the file and create the image folder in the azure portal?

Comment: Can you share the link of your web application?

Comment: Hi, the link to the Web Application: http://websitetestbf.azurewebsites.net on the main site there are 3 picture

Comment: Blob storage is *not* a requirement for storing images. Have you verified that your image was even deployed? Have you looked at `yourwebsite.scm.azurewebsites.net` and browsed your uploaded content (which will be in `d:\home\site`) to see if your images are there where expected?

Comment: Indeed, checking if issue is runtime or deployment time is the first step. See [this article](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-vs-runtime-issues).

Comment: i think its because the images folder is not created after publishing. just drag and drop a file in to this folder in your visual studio. then publish the images will appear. having a file in the folder tells visual studio that this folder needs to be published

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think its because the images folder is not created after publishing. just drag and drop a file in to this folder in your visual studio. then publish the images will appear. having a file in the folder tells visual studio that this folder needs to be published

Comment: Update: you can right click on folder then got settings and change copy setting to copy if newer or always copy.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on image folder of the project and Include in project did the trick for me, earlier it was excluded from the project.